# Orientation rotation sometimes going off angle

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning from a book, and working with orientation changes.

I don't understand why this happens: When I test my app through Corona Simulator, if I rotate my object on screen fast. It's angle goes wacky.

Here's my code:

```
local portrait = display.newText("Portrait", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, native.systemFont, 24) 
local landscape = display.newText("Landscape", display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2, native.systemFont, 24) 
portrait:setFillColor(1, 1, 1)
portrait.alpha = 1 
landscape:setFillColor(1, 1, 1) 
landscape.alpha = 0 
local function onOrientationChange (event) 
    if (event.type =="landscapeRight" or event.type == "landscapeLeft") then 
        local newAngle = landscape.rotation - event.delta 
        transition.to( landscape, {time= 150, rotation = newAngle}) 
        transition.to( portrait, {rotation = newAngle}) 
        portrait.alpha = 0 
        landscape.alpha = 1
    else 
        local newAngle = portrait.rotation - event.delta
        transition.to( portrait, {time= 150, rotation = newAngle})
        transition.to( landscape, {rotation = newAngle})
        portrait.alpha = 1
        landscape.alpha = 0
    end
end 

Runtime:addEventListener( "orientation", onOrientationChange )
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "wonky"? Like print the values of newAngle that you get in one of the two if blocks and put at end of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening mainly due to the `transitions` in progress. SO, you have to stop certain transitions before calling another. So:

First initialize an array holding transitions, just above `function onOrientationChange (event)`

```
  local trans = {}
```

Then name all transitions:

```
  -- Inside 1st if --
  trans[1] = transition.to( landscape, {time= 150, rotation = newAngle})
  trans[2] = transition.to( portrait, {rotation = newAngle})
  ...
  ...
  --Inside 2nd if --
  trans[3] = transition.to( portrait, {time= 150, rotation = newAngle})
  trans[4] = transition.to( landscape, {rotation = newAngle})
```

Then just below line:`local newAngle = landscape.rotation - event.delta`, stop all transitions,
and set the rotation directly to value = `newAngle`:

```
  -- Inside 1st if (just above 'trans[1] = transition.to...')--
  for i=1,4 do if(trans[i])then transition.cancel(trans[i]) end end
  portrait.rotation = newAngle
  ...
  ...
  --Inside 2nd if  (just above 'trans[3] = transition.to...')--
  for i=1,4 do if(trans[i])then transition.cancel(trans[i]) end end
  landscape.rotation = newAngle
```

**Note:** Here I've cancelled all transitions before calling another. Usually, you only needed to cancel transitions which are in progress.

Keep Coding............... :)

Comment: +1 and don't need to keep all four trans because there should be at most one transition for portrait and one for landscape at any moment; for clarity I would use if landscapeTrans then landscapeTrans.stop() end landscapeTrans = transition.to...

Comment: @Schollii: You are correct.Thanks. I've written it so for simplicity(otherwise declarig each transiton with dissimilar names may introduce more lines for cancelling). And feel free to edit always. Keep Coding............ :)